# Преобразовать br в p

Tags: php

Как с помощи php переносимую строку преобразовать в параграф

Есть такой текст

```
Вася купил рогатую козу, но коза была всегда вредной и бодала Васю.
<br /><br />
Васька устал от таких мучений и решил продать козочку.
<br /><br />
Пришел на рынок и продал козу в убыток себе.
```

А нужно так

```
<p>Вася купил рогатую козу, но коза была всегда вредной и бодала Васю.</p>
<p>Васька устал от таких мучений и решил продать козочку.</p>
<p>Пришел на рынок и продал козу в убыток себе.</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Разбить строку на массив по двойным тегам `<br /><br />`, полученные элементы "обернуть" в необходимый тег, и преобразовать массив обратно в строку:

```
$str = 'Вася купил рогатую козу, но коза была всегда вредной и бодала Васю.
<br /><br />
Васька устал от таких мучений и решил продать козочку.
<br /><br />
Пришел на рынок и продал козу в убыток себе.';

$str = join(array_map(function($str){
    return "<p>".trim($str)."</p>";
}, preg_split('~(?:<br\s?/>){2}~', $str)));

echo $str;
```

Comment: Человек не оценивает, предлагаю закончить отвечать на его вопросы, я посмотрел его профайл, там все видно. Приходит за помощью но сам не поощряет это. Хоть плюсик от меня

Comment: @Manitikyl я знаю об этой его "особенности". а решения публикую не конкретно для него, а в целом для пользователей, которым эта информация может понадобиться. За `+` благодарю )

Comment: Благородно, если мы заботимся о других людях, тогда можно отвечать на вопрос спустя неделю, тогда для истории сохранится. Но можно конкретно позаботится и об авторе, донести информацию, что если помогли, галочку можно и поставить.

Comment: @Manitikyl, есть варианты как это сделать можно?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie на след вопрос прям в комментарии сразу отписать, мол не ответим и другим не рекомендуем (ибо автор не оценивает вопросы), пока автор не оценит все свои вопросы которые задал.

Comment: @Manitikyl "_галочку можно и поставить_" - но в правилах не говорится, что ТС обязан её поставить. Это уже на совести человека - благодарить или нет.

Comment: @Эдуард, бессовестные люди появились у нас, хд)

Comment: @Эдуард я ему ничего не запрещаю, и других не заставляю, я просто предлагаю(рекомендую) себя тоже уважать, труд должен быть оценен. В правилах не написано что вы обязаны отвечать если знаете решение)

Comment: @Manitikyl "_вы обязаны отвечать если знаете решение)_" - тоже верно ) Но  мне не жаль, если мой ответ останется без отметки "правильный". С другой стороны есть масса случаев, когда т.н. "галка" не проставлена, но есть много голосов "+" -- для кармы это даже существеннее, чем одна галка :)

Comment: Есть, но это все другие случаи, у нас конкретно, человек прям систематически задает несколько вопрос в день, и ни один вопрос не оценивает. по поводу кармы, ну вы-ж тут чтоб другим людям помогать (исходя из предыдущих ваших ответов), а не себе сантиметры увеличивать. Вот сейчас хороший случай донести до автора что если помогли-отблагодари, это ему и в жизни пригодится)

Comment: @Manitikyl я вас понимаю, и человеческое свойство "благодарность" конечно же никто не отменял :) Просто как вы предполагаете "донести до автора"? Рассмотрим конкретный случай - ТС запостил вопрос. Вы не ответили. Я не ответил. Ещё не ответили 3-5 чел. Но всё равно кто-то напишет ответ, пусть даже и кривой, но задачу тс вполне решающий. Разве не лучше было бы сразу написать людское решение, тем более зная, что это решение не касается конкретно одного человека, т.к. любой ищущий может его забрать? Ну и в конце концов тс зарегит новый акк, и снова будет неблагодарно вопрошать - а вы это не знать

Comment: @Эдуард я открыт для ваших предложений) Достаточно комментария, а через какое-то время - ответ, чтобы автор увидел.

Comment: @Manitikyl мне не понятен ваш последний комментарий. На счёт предложений - согласитесь, что вы не будете мониторить посты в истории, и что всегда удобнее решать вопросы по мере их поступления. Я не навязываю вам своё мнение, и более того - вы можете быть с ним итак согласны, и не сообщать об этом здесь.

Comment: @Manitikyl  Благодарю за вашу критику. Да мне не жалко плюсик поставить, просто политика данного сайта не позволяет оценивать с рейтингом меньше 15 и до вчерашнего дня не мог оценивать.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Да я не настаиваю на ответах, но тем не менее вроде сайт "Вором - Ответ" ну то что не оценивал ответ выше.

Comment: @Позитивонлайн не плюсики, а есть галочка - что ответ правильный и вас устроил

Comment: @Позитивонлайн к слову будет сказано - каждая галочка увеличивает вашу репутацию на 2 балла, но для одного вопроса вы можете поставить только одну галку.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант *(велосипедик)* можно рассмотреть:

```
$string = 'Вася купил рогатую козу, но коза была всегда вредной и бодала Васю.
<br /><br />
Васька устал от таких мучений и решил продать козочку.
<br /><br />
Пришел на рынок и продал козу в убыток себе.';

echo preg_replace("~^([А-Я])(.+?)$\s?~m", "<p>$1$2</p>", strip_tags($string));
```

Comment: и вас тож касается

Comment: @Manitikyl, делает из нас ФРИлансеров)